# Choppy and pixelated video on Macbook Air 5,1. Unable to run/view HD videos at all

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, macbook-air

I'm currently running 13.04 (I try to extend the little help I can by submitting bug reports) and the video is extremely choppy and pix-elated on any video program I run (vlc, mplayer, totem etc.), any flash or html5 videos, and HD videos won't play in a reasonable way at all (entire frames get skipped and video footage is completely distorted; I would say it's about 10 FPS on HD videos, really extremely bad quality). Also, I had this exact problem on 12.04 and 12.10 and was kind of hoping 13.04 would be better, but it is not. Video in Mac OSX works excellent, no lag or quality loss, works perfect in that OS. I would attach some sort of log file or output but I don't know how and would need directions to do so.

Specs - Macbook Air 5,1 ,8 gig ram , 256 ssd , Intel® Core™ i7-3667U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4 , Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

How can I fix this?

Please assist.

Comment: This should be [a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) rather than a question on Ask Ubuntu. ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) This will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).

Comment: I don't understand how this is a bug. Please elaborate. Even if it is a bug, wouldn't more people have reported this problem by now? From searching google, no one has this problem with Macbook Air 5,1.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when going into "Suspend to Ram" and back, it fixes the issue for me.
Seems a bug in the way the HD4000 chip is initialized.
Note - that I saw a "checking battery state" at the boot up, so I suppose disabling it should also fix it... Will see what I can do about it.

Comment: I tried suspending to ram but it didn't resolve for me, but thanks very much for your help. By the way I created a bug report, maybe you want to mark yourself as affected by it as well - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1103236